# Is there a way to check if an object is being hovered on with an if statement with kaboomJS?

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I've been taking a look at this [replit](https://kaboomold.slmjkdbtl.repl.co/), and it seems like it's the alpha version of kaboomJS. In the area() section of the page it says that this is a way to return a true value when an object is being hovered on. Though it seems like it's not option anymore. Does it exist and I'm not just seeing it, or do I need to make my own?

```
if (obj.isHovered()) {
     //...
});
```